# Hard crash of .NET Core 3.1 app using RestSharp ExecuteAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, restsharp

I've been experiencing this for a while with RestSharp, and worked around it by using TaskCompletionSource.

I recently upgraded to the latest version of RestSharp (106.11.4), and still seeing it, so I wanted to ask if anyone knows a potential cause.

Right now I have to define USE_TASK_COMPLETION_SOURCE, or my console app will hard shutdown on the ExecuteAsync call.

I tried throwing a ConfigureAwait(false) in there, as a guess, but that didn't change anything.

Seems like a pretty normal use case; anyone ever seen this before (and solved it)?

Crashes:

```
                    return await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Works:

```
                    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

                    client.ExecuteAsync(request, r =>
                    {
                        tcs.SetResult(r);
                    });

                    if (!tcs.Task.Wait(DEFAULT_REST_TIMEOUT))
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"REST request timed out after [{DEFAULT_REST_TIMEOUT}].");

                    return tcs.Task.Result;
```

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this? I am hitting the same issue on a piece of OpenApi-generated Client SDK because it used RestClient Async under the hood. Works perfectly when called from AspNetCore app... dies a horrible silent death when run from an Xunit integration test.

Comment: I actually ended up writing my own REST client to avoid the problem, and get more control over it.